# ML/DL Prediction on whole input rather than row by row

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, multiclass-classification

I have tabular data from a sensor measuring various features. When the sensor is "off" it will report zero as values. I am training some machine learning models kNN, XGBoost, and NN for the purpose of classification. Here's the issue I am facing: I can train and predict on a row by row basis; however it would be better to classify a range as whole rather than a row by row basis. Another issue to this is that the range can vary in size. For a very basic example, please see this diagram illustrating the range.
[image]

I have a basic Keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And the training data is shaped with 20 features and 4 classes. How would I:
1.) Format my training data
2.) Shape input data to classify as a "whole" rather than row by row
3.) While this has been talking about using keras. Can the same input shaping/training be applied to XGBoost or a kNN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the blue line in that graph represents your targets. Here is a fundamental issue I see with something like predicting the range as a whole instead of sample by sample.

Assuming that there is some reasonable logic that could collapse the range of samples into one (taking mean per each feature, or concatenation, or whatever...), obviously you would first need to identify the range itself. This range identification step is however dependent on the knowledge of target (at least it seems like that based on the presented graph).

If the preprocessing step is dependent on the knowledge of the target, you would need to know the target for the test set as well before you could preprocess the data and make the predictions. In other words, you would need to know the outcome before you could make the prediction which would then be rather pointless.

You have stated that you are trying to perform classification but your target seems to be continuous. I don't know what your classes are or what patterns they are associated with but you would need to bin the target before you could start solving this as a classification problem. You would most likely lose a lot of information by doing this.

Therefore, I would start by solving it as a regression problem. Trying to predict that continuous target for each sample. Once you have that, you can apply some patter matching logic to identify the class for a given sample/range (for example, you could slice the sequence of targets/predictions from the previous step, associate each slice with the desired class and use this data as a new dataset for some classification algorithm).

As for the variable length inputs. Some deep learning architectures allow you to work with input of variable length, such as RNNs or adaptive pooling. You may try to do this one you know how to predict the continuous target as mentioned before. Non-deep-learning algorithms usually expect all samples to have the same shape so there is no general/automatic way of reusing the same input between them and deep learning algorithms that work with input of variable length.